# asp vb save excel file in particular path

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, excel, vbscript

refering to this link [Creating an Excel Application from VB.Net](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/vb.net/vb.net_excel_sheet.htm)

I want to save my excel file to this path:

```
C:\Users\asdfme\Documents
```

with the filename format `[PROJ_DATE].xls`     example:PROJ_20140703.xls
here is my code:

```
    Protected Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Call temporaryValue()
        Dim appXL As Excel.Application
        Dim wbXl As Excel.Workbook
        Dim shXL As Excel.Worksheet
        Dim raXL As Excel.Range
        Dim strPathExcel As String

        ' Start Excel and get Application object.
        appXL = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
        appXL.Visible = True
        ' Add a new workbook.
        wbXl = appXL.Workbooks.Add
        shXL = wbXl.ActiveSheet
        ' Add table headers going cell by cell.
        Dim heads() As String = {"", "MONo", "PostingDate", "DocDate", "SBU", "Operation", "Resource", "TimeType", "StartDate", "StartTime", "EndDate", "EndTime", "NoofResources", "Remarks", "Quantity", "Rejects"}
        For head1 As Integer = 1 To 15
            shXL.Cells(1, head1).Value = heads(head1)
        Next
        Dim body() As String = {"", txtmo.Text, PostingDate, DocDate, SBU, Operation, Session("user"), (ddltype.SelectedValue).ToUpper, lblsDate.Text, lblsTime.Text, lbleDate.Text, lbleTime.Text, no_ofres, lblrem.Text, txtgoods.Text, txtrejects.Text}
        For body1 As Integer = 1 To 15
            shXL.Cells(2, body1).Value = body(body1)
        Next
        appXL.Visible = True
        appXL.UserControl = True
        ' Release object references.
        wbXl.SaveAs(Filename:="C:\Users\asdfme\Documents\PROJ_20140703.xls")
        raXL = Nothing
        shXL = Nothing
        wbXl = Nothing
        appXL.Quit()
        appXL = Nothing
        Exit Sub
Err_Handler:
        MsgBox(Err.Description, vbCritical, "Error: " & Err.Number)
    End Sub
```

when i run this code,

- it only create an excel file and ask me if i want to save the file.
- what i want is whenever i run this, the file will save with the file name format (written above) in the path i declare.

Please help. thank you

Comment: Fine, and the question is?

Comment: I edit my question. :) I want to save the file directly to my path: C:\Users\asdfme\Documents without asking me whether to save or dont save the file. thank you

Comment: `wbXl.SaveAs(Filename:="C:\Users\asdfme\Documents\PROJ_20140703.xls")`

Comment: how can i set my file name?

Comment: how you get the file name ??

Comment: are you trying to create file (`PROJ_20140703.xls`) randomly or fixed manner ??

Comment: Microsoft Excel cannot access the file 'C:\Users\asdfme\Documents\A9478100'. There are several possible reasons:

• The file name or path does not exist.
• The file is being used by another program.
• The workbook you are trying to save has the same name as a currently open workbook.

Comment: can you edit my code, and put the code you are suggesting? please..

Comment: provide your entire code

Comment: the filename is just a fixed manner.

Comment: Whats your EXCEL VERSION ??

Comment: i have tried your code its working correctly on my environment, try to close all `excel` sheets in your computer and change the `file location`, i used to save the excel file to `wbXl.SaveAs(Filename:="C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Desktop\PROJ_20140703.xls")`

Comment: Let me get this straight. Your code runs on an ASP.NET page on the SERVER SIDE and you want to save this file on the CLIENT machine? If this is the case there are no chance you could do that with that code on a live hosted server. The path your express is relative to the SERVER machine, not the client one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Dim myXlsFileName As String = "PROJ_" & " " & Format(Now.Date, "yyyyddMM") & ""
wbXl.SaveAs(Filename:="C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Desktop\" & myXlsFileName & ".xls")
```

Comment: thanks hector, but how will i know if the file is already exist?

Comment: `If Not File.Exists("C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Desktop\" & myXlsFileName & ".xls") Then
                'create file
            End If`

Comment: hi hector, you help me a lot but i am having a problem in saving the file again

Comment: thank you hector ^_^ i solve it with the file name ^_^ thank you again